# Tail-recursive sum of elements

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, tail-recursion

I am currently trying to learn about tail recursion in F# so say I have a function that takes in a list multiplies 3 to each element and then gets the sum of the list. Which the code would look something like this

```
let calc L = L |> List.map (fun x -> (x*3)) |>  List.sum
```

How would I make this a Tail Recursive function with a helper function.

```
let _calc result L = 
  match L with 
  | [] -> result
  | hd::tl -> ???

let calc L = 
  match L with 
  | [] -> raise (System.ArgumentException("List cannot be empty"))
  | hd::tl _calc hd tl
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to give the answer away completely, so:

Start with the tail-recursive definition of `sum`

```
let rec _calc result L = 
  match L with 
  | [] -> result
  | hd::tl -> _calc (result + hd) tl

let sum L = _calc 0 L
```

Now what needs to change to multiply each element by 3?

(Also note that `let calc L = L |> List.map (fun x -> (x*3)) |>  List.sum` will return 0 on empty list, not raise an exception. No need to force an exception in your tail-recursive version either, unless it's a requirement.)

Comment: Just to make this answer complete, the `_calc` function needs the `rec` keyword, unless it's created in a module or namespace marked `rec`.